Binary injection, redirect flow to the origin entry point
I am currently working on a binary injection school project where I need to inject my code into a running 64-bit Windows executable and then ensure that the execution flow returns smoothly to the original entry point of the host application. I would like to know what is the best method to do that.
I don't find a lot of information about it and my actual solution is probably not the best one : I save the original entrypoint in the PE header with a specific offset (+ 0x20 in my case) and I redirect into it at the end of the injected section. That will probably work, but that is clearly not clean.
Any advice or pointers to resources that discuss managing execution flow in injected binaries would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Git Repository Link
